# Gradle application variant mergeAssets not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to use the gradle `applicationVariants` `mergeAssets` task to remove some unused assets files from my apk.

Even though I'm able to print the line "*this line is printed*", when the application variant is 'run', the `variant.mergeAssets.doFirst {}` does not seem to be called, as I never see the output "*this line is not printed*" in my gradle console. The asset I'm trying to remove does not get removed either, but it seems like the code to remove it is never executed.

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried moving the entire `android.applicationVariants` task outside of `buildTypes`, I've tried nesting it in `release{}`.. nothing I've tried seems to work.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), file('proguard-project.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    publicBeta.initWith(buildTypes.release)
    publicBeta {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), file('proguard-project.txt')
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        println 'this line is printed'
        variant.mergeAssets.doFirst {
            println 'this line is never printed'
            File fonts = file("${rootDir}/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview/robototextview/2.0.1/assets/fonts")
            if (fonts.exists()) {
                for (File file : fonts.listFiles()) {
                    if (file.getName().contains("RobotoSlab")) {
                        println("delete " + file.getName() + " font")
                        file.delete()
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the gradle console output, for brevity:

```
Executing tasks: [:shuttle_paid:assembleRelease]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
this line is printed
this line is printed
this line is printed
:shuttle_library:compileLint
:shuttle_library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:preBuild
:shuttle_library:preReleaseBuild
:shuttle_library:checkReleaseManifest
:shuttle_library:preDebugBuild
:shuttle_library:preDebugTestBuild
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:compileLint
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:preBuild
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:preReleaseBuild
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:checkReleaseManifest
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:preDebugBuild
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:preDebugTestBuild
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices5077Library UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:castcompanionlibrary-android:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:prepareComGithubJohnkilAndroidRobototextviewRobototextview210Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices5077Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:prepareComLarswerkmanHoloColorPicker14Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:prepareShuttleLibrariesCastcompanionlibraryAndroidUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:shuttle_library:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_library:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:preBuild
:shuttle_paid:preReleaseBuild
:shuttle_paid:checkReleaseManifest
:shuttle_paid:preDebugBuild
:shuttle_paid:prePublicBetaBuild
:shuttle_paid:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:prepareComGithubJohnkilAndroidRobototextviewRobototextview210Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices5077Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:prepareComLarswerkmanHoloColorPicker14Library UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:prepareShuttleLibrariesCastcompanionlibraryAndroidUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:prepareShuttleShuttle_libraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:prepareReleaseDependencies
:shuttle_paid:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:lintVitalRelease
:shuttle_paid:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:proguardRelease UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:validateReleaseSigning
:shuttle_paid:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:zipalignRelease UP-TO-DATE
:shuttle_paid:assembleRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.682 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that is printed will always be printed because it gets executed in the configuration phase. ( see [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) )

Your gradle console output shows all the merge*Resources tasks being skipped as UP-TO-DATE. This means that the inputs and the outputs have not changed since last time the tasks were executed, so gradle does not execute them again. Unfortunately, Gradle is not yet smart enough to know that you have changed the task implementation and that it should not skip the task.

Try running a clean to force the task to run